# Put query string after hash in angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-rewriting

I have a little AngularJS search app that initially has data sent via GET from a form in a (non-AngularJS) HTML page:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" name="librarysearch" id="us-form" action="#" method="get" >
```

I use some jQuery to submit the form to an AngularJS app:

```
$("#us-form").attr("action", "/unified-search/app/#/results?q=" + q).submit();
```

My Angular $routeProvider passes the ball to the FormCtrl. The FormCtrl grabs the query param and uses $location.path to send the parameter to the ResultsCtrl:

```
$location.path('/results').search( { q: q} );
```

The ResultsCtrl uses the query parameter to call various services and present the results to the user. This all works splendidly. So why am I writing a question here?

Well, the URL generated from a search is like this:

```
.../unified-search/app/?q=physiology#/results?q=physiology
```

There are two issues with this:

i) it is not aesthetically pleasing to observe

ii) it works in most browsers, but IE/Edge strips everything after the '#'. In doing so, my AngularJS app is not found - help!

I have tried many regexes in .htaccess to rewrite the URL, but IE will always put the query string BEFORE the '#' - it needs to be AFTER the '#' for my AngularJS app to work. How can I achieve this please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW I solved this by using POST instead of GET in the referring form. This fixed the URL format to:

```
.../unified-search/app/#/results?q=physiology
```

which is what I wanted, and this also solved the issue in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is that you are setting the path and search params using `$location.path('/results').search({q: q})`. This is appending `/results` after the hash and then adding the query to the URL. You shouldn't need to do that because your jQuery form submit is already handling the navigation.

Comment: thanks @Shaun. Okay, I tried routing straight to the ResultsCtrl and getting the query value using $routeParams. This works but produces the same result which fails in IE.

Comment: Is this problem specific to IE?